# Making a line in html with the path element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to draw a line between two elements in html/js using svg and path elements and it works but I need a way to draw arcs that are rotated so it is smother. This is my first post here so sorry if it is not easy to understand

I tryed to draw a arc that is rotated to be smooth with a line. image [image: Svg] My code is
`
function add_connection(start, end) {

```
// Goto start - 2 on the y axis
// Draw Arc
// Goto end + 2 on the y axis
// Draw Arc
// Finish

const move_start = "M {SX} {SY}" // SY - 2
const draw_arc = " A 1 1 0 0 0 {SX} {SY} " // SY + 2
const draw_line = "L {EX} {EY}" // EY + 2
// draw_arc

const node = document.createElement("svg")

// Define Variables
var path_html = ""
const start_x = start.left + (start.width/2)
const start_y = start.top + (start.height/2)
const end_x = end.left + (end.width/2)
const end_y = end.top + (end.height/2)

// HTML Start
path_html += "<path d='"

// Path Data

path_html += move_start.replace("{SY}", start_y-2).replace("{SX}", start_x)
path_html += draw_arc.replace("{SY}", start_y+2).replace("{SX}", start_x)
path_html += draw_line.replace("{EY}", end_y+2).replace("{EX}", end_x)
path_html += draw_arc.replace("{SY}", start_y+2).replace("{SX}", start_x)

// HTML End
path_html += " Z'>"

// Add Node
node.innerHTML = path_html
document.getElementById("paths").appendChild(node)

console.log("Created Connection")`
```

start and end are bounding boxes

Comment: Could drawing a line (`<line>`) with [linecaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap) do it or would there be more complicated cases where the path (`<path>`) with arcs be necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two line elements you can create the same effect by setting the [stroke-linecap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap) and two different stroke widths.

```js
const svg01 = document.getElementById('svg01');

add_connection({left:5,top:5},{left:95,top:25});

function add_connection(start, end) {
  let g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
  let line1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
  let line2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
  line1.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
  line2.setAttribute('stroke', 'yellow');
  line1.setAttribute('stroke-width', '5');
  line2.setAttribute('stroke-width', '3');
  line1.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
  line2.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
  line1.setAttribute('x1', start.left);
  line1.setAttribute('y1', start.top);
  line1.setAttribute('x2', end.left);
  line1.setAttribute('y2', end.top);
  line2.setAttribute('x1', start.left);
  line2.setAttribute('y1', start.top);
  line2.setAttribute('x2', end.left);
  line2.setAttribute('y2', end.top);
  g.appendChild(line1);
  g.appendChild(line2);
  svg01.appendChild(g);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg01" viewBox="0 0 100 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you i found a more complex solution using math to calculate the outside and the end positions for arcs